# What is kWh vs W?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question says

> A household has solar PV cells installed on their roof. If they have a $1.5 ~ kW$ system that produces $5.85 ~ kWh$ of electricity daily, how much electricity will be generated in one year?

So they have $1.5 ~kW$ solar panel (what does that mean?) that produces $5.85 ~ kWh$ of electricity each day --> so every day it produces $5.85 ~kW$ of energy per hour? so $5.85 \times 25$ = total energy produced in a day? Why do we know it is $1.5 ~ kW$ then?

The answer is $2135 ~ kW/h$ for a year. Why per hour? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You will find this easier if you ignore the $1.5$kW completely and read $5.85$kWh of electricity as $5.85$ units of electrical energy.  So the question becomes: *"A household has solar PV cells installed on their roof. If they have a system that produces $5.85$ units of electrical energy daily, how many units of electrical energy will be generated in one year?"*

Comment: @Henry you sir are a God...I am just going to mentally substitute kWh with units of electrical energy. I have my final high school exams tomorrow and I haven't even covered this chapter, lol...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are units of power and energy.

- W: Watt, power
- kW:  kilowatt, power
- kWh: kilowatt hour, energy

If we said "Blah, blah PV, blah.  If they have blah that produces 5.85 kWh of electricity daily, how much electricity will be generated in one year?", you would be led to compute: $$\begin{align*}
    365 \cdot 5.85 \,\mathrm{kWh}
\end{align*}$$
which will be some number of $\mathrm{kWh}$.  The "/" is a typo.  It is probably derived from the alternative way of writing the unit: "$\mathrm{kW} \cdot \mathrm{h}$.

It's important to practice ignoring the extraneous information.

Answer (score 0):

kWh is a commercial unit used in factories 1 kWh =3.6 * 10^6 joules and 1 kW = 1000W

Comment: The first equation in this answer is correct, but the second, $1$ kWh = $1000$ W, is not; it equates an amount of energy to an amount of power.